# Laravel Blade loop through config array variable

Tags: laravel, config, laravel-blade

In my `config/locale.php` I have an array `displayLanguage` which contains 'key => value' pairs.
How can I loop through this array in blade?
I have tried the following:

```php
@foreach ( {{ Config::get('app.locale.displayLanguage') }}  as $itemKey => $itemVal)
    {{ $itemKey }}
@endforeach
```

I am getting syntax error, unexpected '<'. Tried also some other variation to loop this var without passing it through the controller.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your file is in `config/locale.php` then you call `config('locale.displayLanguage')`;

```
@foreach(config('locale.displayLanguage') as $key => $value)
    {{ $key }}
@endforeach
```

I am using the global helper `config()` in a blade file.

It also appears you have extra curly braces in your `foreach` loop