# How to get config in blade file with Laravel 8.x

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, config

**Here is my problem i've read already a lot of thing, I am actually following this tutorial**

1. https://5balloons.info/localization-laravel-multi-language-language-switcher/
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=po4Xt1G3gcc

But I can't get it working, I always get error and I've been stuck on this for the past 4 hours. Everyone who is using this technic seems to be able to make it works but not me.

**I've already looked all these posts**

1. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade
2. [Laravel - htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43217872/laravel-htmlspecialchars-expects-parameter-1-to-be-string-object-given)
3. [Laravel Get Config Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49183829/laravel-get-config-variable)
4. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/problem-in-retrieving-the-data-in-viewblade-laravel
5. https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-access-config-file-values-in-laravel-using-config
6. [Converting an array of arrays from Laravel's collection into an object with an array in json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36849481/converting-an-array-of-arrays-from-laravels-collection-into-an-object-with-an-a)
7. [Laravel Blade loop through config array variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42359861/laravel-blade-loop-through-config-array-variable)
8. https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multidimensional.asp
9. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/configuration
10. [Laravel: how to get direct config value in blade template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53631037/laravel-how-to-get-direct-config-value-in-blade-template)

And more links are missing.
**The thing is whatever I do I either get the error it needs an array not a string (The third line is creating this error):**
[image: Error#1]

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        {{ config('languages')[App::getLocale()] }}
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            @foreach (config('languages') as $lang => $language)
                    @if ($lang != App::getLocale())
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('lang.switch', $lang) }}"> {{$language}}</a>
                    @endif
            @endforeach
        </div>

    </li>
```

**Or I get the error telling me that my array is empty (The third line is creating the error):**
[image: Error2]

```
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        {{ config('languages.*')[App::getLocale()] }}
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            @foreach (config('languages') as $lang => $language)
                    @if ($lang != App::getLocale())
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('lang.switch', $lang) }}"> {{$language}}</a>
                    @endif
            @endforeach
        </div>

    </li>
```

Or I get the error telling me it needs a string not an array:

**Here is how my config is made:**
config/languages.php

```
    <?php

return [
        'en' => [
            'display' => 'English',
            'flag-icon' => 'us',
        ],

        'fr' => [
            'display' => 'Français',
            'flag-icon' => 'fr',
        ],

        'es' => [
            'display' => 'Spanish',
            'flag-icon' => 'es',
        ],
];
```

**I also tried this and tried to access it with config(languages.languages):**

```
    <?php

return [
    'languages' => [
        'en' => [
            'display' => 'English',
            'flag-icon' => 'us',
        ],

        'fr' => [
            'display' => 'Français',
            'flag-icon' => 'fr',
        ],

        'es' => [
            'display' => 'Spanish',
            'flag-icon' => 'es',
        ],
    ],
];
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I simply copied and pasted everything from the tutorial for the 10th time and it worked, IDK why, tho I changed Config::get by config()